# Adjacent doors hitting each other

Tags: doors

I have two doors at a 90-degree angle to one another and the doors hit each other when they are opened the full way.

I guess I could mount a door stop on one of the doors, but it seems kind of weird to put a doorstop on a door.

Another option might be to remount both the doors to either/both change the handedness or swing direction, but that would be a lot more work.

How can I keep these doors from hitting when opened?

Comment: Hinge mounted door stops.    reversing swing is not a simple task but it can be done. Mortising hinges is quite precise work any mistakes in locating the hinges will cause improper door function. Second chances are not an option. Then you have to fill the old mounting locations on door and jamb and the bore holes.

Comment: I put a door stop on my bathroom door, It opens into and against the bathtub. Putting a doorstop on the tub was not an option. I used the spring type doorstop.

Comment: @Kris -- hinge stops tend to take a lot of stress -- they might hold up OK in a house, they might not, depends on how hard your family is on doors :)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution: Make one of them close to avoid clashing.

I reversed my kitchen door so it opens into the hallway instead of into the room.  That means it can clash with the cloakroom door if that's left half open.  I solved it by fitting a (very gentle, in fact modified with a weaker spring) automatic closer to the cloakroom door, so it doesn't stop half open.

Rehanging a door can be tricky but is perfectly doable with reasonable DIY skills.  It's one of the simplest tasks for which you need a decent set of chisels (in fact it's the main reason I even have chisels).  The job needs proper planning: when I did mine there was enough space on the new side of the frame to make it simple but had it been on a different (non-structural) wall it would have been much harder.

Answer (score 0):

I did indeed end up putting two stops on one of the doors at the top and bottom and it works ok.

One key thing is that I put the stops on the door that faces the length of the hallway. This is important because you don't want to have a door stop jutting out into a corridor or hallway where someone could trip over it or knock things into it, like bags or luggage.

By putting stops only on the door at the end of the hallway they worked fine and created no problems.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with my front door and the adjacent garage door. The solution was a unique doorstop that is slightly longer than normal and has a roller on the end of the stop as shown below:
6 inch doorstop with roller
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Viur.jpg)

[image: Stopper rolls along door]
If one door is narrower than the other it should be installed on the narrower door.
Here is the link:https://www.doorware.com/site/product.cfm?id=349175

Comment: I bought what looks to be the identical part.  Hard to find and cost $50.  I should have done more analysis of my problem before ordering though, because it doesn't seem like it will solve the issue entirely.  It may keep the handle of one door from crashing in to the surface of the other, but not the handles from hitting each other.  The roller-stopper is not greater in length than the sum of the two door handles.  So the handles, being at the same height as each other, will crash together.  Perhaps the roller-bumper combined with some new low-profile handles will solve it.